# How do bash return values of functions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to understand how do bash functions return values.
I have created the 4 following functions, and I do not understand how it really works:

```bash
#test1.sh
#!/bin/bash



function a() {
    ls -la
}

function b() {
    _b=$(ls -la)
}

function c() {
    _c=$(ls -la)
    return $_c
}

function d() {
    _d=$(ls -la)
    return "$_d"
}
echo "A1:"
a
echo "----------"
echo "A2:"
ret_a=$(a)
echo "$ret_a"
echo "----------"
echo "B1:"
b
echo "----------"
echo "B2:"
ret_b="$(b)"
echo "$ret_b"
echo "----------"
echo "C1:"
c
echo "----------"
echo "C2:"
ret_c="$(c)"
echo "$ret_c"
echo "----------"
echo "D1:"
d
echo "----------"
echo "D2:"
ret_d=$(d)
echo "$ret_d"
echo "----------"
```

When I execute `./test1.sh` it provides me the following output:

```bash
$ ./test1.sh
A1:
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  2 mayday mayday  4096 jul 15 09:18 .
drwxrwxrwt 29 root     root     12288 jul 15 11:46 ..
-rwxrw-r--  1 mayday mayday   523 jul 15 11:44 test1.sh
----------
A2:
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  2 mayday mayday  4096 jul 15 09:18 .
drwxrwxrwt 29 root     root     12288 jul 15 11:46 ..
-rwxrw-r--  1 mayday mayday   523 jul 15 11:44 test1.sh
----------
B1:
----------
B2:

----------
C1:
./test1.sh: line 15: return: total: numeric argument required
----------
C2:
./test1.sh: line 15: return: total: numeric argument required

----------
D1:
./test1.sh: line 20: return: total 20
drwxrwxr-x  2 mayday mayday  4096 jul 15 09:18 .
drwxrwxrwt 29 root     root     12288 jul 15 11:46 ..
-rwxrw-r--  1 mayday mayday   523 jul 15 11:44 test1.sh: numeric argument required
----------
D2:
./test1.sh: line 20: return: total 20
drwxrwxr-x  2 mayday mayday  4096 jul 15 09:18 .
drwxrwxrwt 29 root     root     12288 jul 15 11:46 ..
-rwxrw-r--  1 mayday mayday   523 jul 15 11:44 test1.sh: numeric argument required
```

My questions are:

1. Does `function a` return the `ls` output without the `return` command? why?
2. Why is different the `return`command from `function c` and `function d`?
3. What does the `total: numeric argument required` mean at `function c` and `function d`?
4. As summary, If i wanted to create a new `function`, that take into a variable the result of the ls executed in the previous function, what would be the best approach from the previous ones? i.e:

```bash
function ls_printer() {
    return $(ls -la)
}
function ls_printer_reader() {
    _my_variable=ls_printer
    echo "$_my_variable"
}
ls_printer_reader
```

Comment: **(1)** *return value* (or *return status*) is the *exit status* of a command and it's an integer in range [0, 256). if a func trys to return `N` which is `> 255` then the real return value will be `N % 256`. a command's return value will be saved in `$?`.  **(2)** shell's `$( command ... )` is used to get the *output* of the command. the result is a string.

Comment: Shell functions are more like subroutines. They aren't expressions that evaluate to some value. Like any other command, though, they inherit their standard output from their caller, and so any commands inside the function (like `ls`) inherit *their* standard output from the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a bit of background:

1. Unlike other programming languages in shell functions return their status codes to the calling shell and that code is stored in the `$?` system variable.
2. `return` is a command which sends a **numerical** status code to the calling shell. You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-command-in-linux-with-examples/).

So now lets walk through your code:

```
function a() {
    ls -la
}

echo "A1:"
a
```

Basically calling the a function which will give us the same output as `ls -la`.

```
echo "A2:"
ret_a=$(a)
echo "$ret_a"
```

So now your assigning the output of `$(a)` to the variable `ret_a`. since `$(a)` is basically the same as calling the `a` function this means you are assigning the variable a couple of lines of text (the output of `ls -la`).
So in conclusion, variable `ret_a` is just a multi string.

```
function b() {
    _b=$(ls -la)
}
 
echo "B1:"
b
```

So, in this time around function b just assigns a value to a variable named `_b` and it's value is, once again, the lines of text coming from `ls -la`.
Nothing is printed to the terminal as variable assignment is silent...

```
echo "B2:"
ret_b="$(b)"
```

So now you are assigning the output of `$(b)` to `ret_b`. In this case `b` is executed since you've put `$(b)` in double quotes "" and thus shell can make the substitution.
As explained above, there is no output from the `b` method and so an empty string is assigned to `ret_b`. In the end an empty line is printed to the terminal.

```
function c() {
    _c=$(ls -la)
    return $_c
}

echo "C1:"
c
```

In function `c` the variable `_c` is , once again, assigned the value of `$(ls -la)` which is a couple lines of strings. After that the function attempts to return a numerical value but fails since you are trying to return a string. What is actually going on is that the function `return` is passed multiple strings separated by the new-line character then it ignores all lines other then the first - in this case "total". The error "./test1.sh: line 15: return: total: numeric argument required" is printed once `c` is called.

```
echo "C2:"
ret_c="$(c)"
echo "$ret_c"
```

`ret_c` is assigned the output of function `c` which in this case is a line of text reading "./test1.sh: line 15: return: total: numeric argument required" and so once echoed this text is the output.

```
function d() {
    _d=$(ls -la)
    return "$_d"
}

echo "D1:"
d
```

Function `d` does the same as function `c`. The addition of the double quotes here makes the `return` function to not only process the first line of text but the entire thing as one big string.
So basically the difference is that in function `c` the `return` function was only processing the first line of text ("total") and in `d` the entire output is passed.
Once again you are trying to `return` a non numeric value and the output is an error message.

```
ret_d=$(d)
echo "$ret_d"
```

Lastly `ret_d` is passed the output of `d` and echos it. The output was explained above.

Now, for your 4th question:

```
function ls_printer() {
ls -la
}
function ls_printer_reader() {
    _my_variable=$(ls_printer)
    echo "$_my_variable"
}
ls_printer_reader
```

If you want an example of returning both strings and numerical values you can read more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615235/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-number-and-string-from-shell-function).

Hope this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

When you want the output of any function, or script in bash, you 'capture' its output. I say capture since scripts and functions in bash do not return values like functions in other programming languages (like cpp, js, python..). They output what they do to stdout, so if you want the result of another function or script in bash, you need to capture its output.
What you did with the $() is called command substitution. What it does is running a sub-shell with what you give it, and outputs it in place, so it is a good way of capturing output of another scripts, or functions, in bash